# GCS: uploading signed URL (generated on Node.js server): multipart headers are inserted in file body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

Context:

- Node.js server deployed in VPS instance.
- Web app client (Vue/Quasar but it's not important)
- Uploading serveral large files (500Mb-1Gb) simultanously.

Steps:

1. Client ask server for signed url, Node process the request and
   return the url.
2. Client uploads to the destination provided at point 1.
3. The result is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryu22DC1TykLzIabb9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pozitie corecta obiecte.jpg"; filename="pozitie corecta obiecte.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿáLExi.... normal jpg file
```

So the GCS also include the headers of the multipart streaming.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
First delete the `contentType` prop from signing function:

```
async function generateV4UploadSignedUrl(fileName) {
    // These options will allow temporary uploading of the file with outgoing
    // Content-Type: application/octet-stream header.
    const options = {
        version       : 'v4',
        action        : 'write',
        expires       : Date.now() + 30 * 60 * 1000 // 30 minutes
        // contentType: 'application/octet-stream', // delete this line!!!
    };
```

Then add in client the content type of the file you're uploading:

```
headers: [{
                        name : 'Content-Type',
                        value: files[0].type
                    }]
```

That's it. Everything works.